# Contests and Challenges? Burn [contest-problem]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Going through the tags, I found that we have a [contest-problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-problem) tag. It would be a good tag, except we already have the [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge).

- [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) has 202 questions tagged.
- [contest-problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-problem) has 18 questions tagged.

It is a synonym to [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge), but they are both after the exact same thing. No differences. Except a programming challenge sounds better than a contest problem, because that makes it seem like there's an issue with a contest!

Could we burninate [contest-problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-problem) and stick to [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge)?

Without it, we'll be left with [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) and [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge).

Comment: Just be aware that some of those 18 questions are actually tagged with the "TopCoder" synonym.

Comment: @Jamal what about those tags? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/community-challenge/synonyms should everything mentioned here be synonyms?

Comment: @Templar: No, those are separate from programming challenges, which are *off-site*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this can be changed.  Contest problems *are* still considered challenges.  The only difference is that contest problems may have certain criteria.  If that's the case, then they should be stated in the question.  We don't get too many actual contest problems, and even then, they're usually not approached too differently from regular programming challenges.

Instead of burninating the tag, I'd recommend making it a synonym.  They are quite similar, and it will still show that the question came from a competition.

Comment: I like it. Making the synonym keeps the closed questions out of the review queue.

Comment: A synonym to [tag:programming-challenge]? If so, I like it too :)

Answer (score 3):

[image]